# Solving a rod cutting problem with recursion

Tags: recursion, algorithm

I'm trying to use Mathematica 10.0. to solve a rod cutting problem with naive recursion. The problem is taken from *Introduction to Algorithm*, 3rd edition.

The length price for rod is defined in the book as

```
price = {1, 5, 8, 9, 10, 17, 17, 20, 24, 30}
```

where the `i`-th element means length `i` can be sold for `price[[i]]`. I want to find the optimal cut for given length to generate maximum profit.

Following the idea of naive recursion given in the book, I write following code:

```
rodcut[price_, length_] := 
  Module[{n = length, q = 0}, 
  If[n == 0, 
    0, 
    For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, 
      q = Max[q, price[[i]] + rodcut[price, n - i]]]; 
      Return[q]]]
```

However, when I run the code `rodcut[price, k]`, it always output outcome `price[[k]]`. It seems like the iteration skips the process and just run the last step `i = k`.

Could anyone give me some help?

Comment: It looks like it's because `i` gets reset to 1 repeatedly, presumably because it has global scope, simply add `i` to the list of symbols being declared locally at the top of your `Module`.

Comment: Or use `Do` instead of `For`.

Comment: @Quantum_Oli You're right. `i` is global variable but I'm wondering how `i` gets to reset to 1 repeatly